# How to pass EventArgs to DelegateCommand?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` project. In Prism as a MVVM framework. I have a custom control (derived from `CocosSharpView`, but that's not important). I'm rising a custom event in that class with a parameter, but can't transfer this parameter to the ViewModel. Here's the code:

The **View** part. I'm firing up a **custom** OnTouched event with some argument:

```
public class CustomCocosSharpView : CocosSharpView
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> OnTouched;
    public CCGameView gameView;

    // ... not important stuff ...

    private void OnViewCreated(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        if (gameView == null)
        {
            gameView = sender as CCGameView;
            if (gameView != null)
            {
                _gameScene = new GameScene(gameView);
                _gameScene.OnTouched += (s, e) =>
                {
                    CustomEventArgs custom = new CustomEventArgs() { Foo = 4 };
                    OnTouched?.Invoke(s, custom);
                };
                gameView.RunWithScene(_gameScene);
            }
        }
        OnCreated?.Invoke(sender, ea);
    }
}

public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML** part:

```
  <mobile:CustomCocosSharpView>
    <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
        <behaviors:EventToCommand EventName="OnTouched"
                                  Command="{Binding OnTouchedCommand}" />        
      </behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </mobile:CustomCocosSharpView>
```

and finally **ViewModel**:

```
    private DelegateCommand<CustomEventArgs> onTouchedCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<CustomEventArgs> OnTouchedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return onTouchedCommand ?? (onTouchedCommand = new DelegateCommand<CustomEventArgs>((arg) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("OnTouchCommand " + arg?.Foo.ToString()); //arg is null. Why?
            }));
        }
    }
```

The question:

**How can I get `CustomEventArgs` argument in the DelegateCommand?** It must be possible! But nothing works:/

Thanks for help!

Comment: I am not really sure that I get what you want exactly ... however I think you are asking for commands with parameters . There is a nice article about that which I just found 

https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Prism 6.3-pre2 you can use the built-in EventToCommand and have complete control over what you pass to the DelegateCommand using either a converter or a path.  You can check out the docs here:  http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Xamarin-Forms/6-EventToCommandBehavior/#using-the-eventtocommandbehavior

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will try that later today. Looks good. Btw. Just to be sure, was it even possible in version `6.2.0` (pass parameter from custom event to command)? This is what I'm using right now

Comment: Not with Prism.  6.2 didn't have the Prism EventToCommand behavior.

Comment: Wait, what? The code I posted was compiled and run with 6.2.0. Actually this is the latest version on nuget. There's definitely `EventToCommand` in Prism 6.2.0. I don't know about parameters - I will be able to test it c.a. 4 hours. Btw. from where do I get 6.3 if it's not on nuget?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Prism's EventToCommand and not something else?  I have in the release notes of 6.3 that EventToCommand was added.  6.3 is in preview right now and you can only see it if you include preview packages.

Comment: Ohhh! I think you're right! I totally forgot I installed `Corcav.Behaviors` before. So technically, if I update `Prism.Core` and `Prism.Forms` to 6.3 I can remove `Corcav.Behaviors`?

Comment: Yes. Actually I just pushed 6.3 as stable. So have at it

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will check it out right now. Btw. Do I need to install Prism in iOS and Android too? Or PCL is enough ?

Comment: Install in all projects

Comment: I have a problem with iOS part of the code where I previously was doing: `Corcav.Behaviors.Infrastructure.Init();`

Comment: and.. now I have this problem with Android as well. With `Corcav.Behaviors`  installed I had it only in iOS.

Comment: delete it and remove Corcav if you don't need it. If you are using other behaviors leave it in.

Comment: 6.3 version doesn't work very well. I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43034805/7727517) another problem. My follow up question is: Is it possible to pass parameter from View to ViewModel using 6.2 version and `Corcav.Behaviors`? It worked great (without parameter). I spent entire weekend and with 6.3 version I can't even reach the point where I was with 6.2 :(((

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 6.3. I can assure you it is your environment. Uninstall the apps from your emulators, delete your obj and bin folders, clean and rebuild.  I am unable to duplicated your issue.

Comment: Ok, so.. I cleaned iOS Simulator by `Reset Content and Settings`, I deleted bin/obj folders, I cleaned solution, reopened Visual Studio, double checked nuget packagest (I use Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193, Prism.Core 6.3 and Prism.Forms 6.3). Double checked Sierra OS, I updated to latest version - 10.12.3. Everything is updated on my MacBook. This code worked perfectly with Prism 6.2 and `Corcav.Behaviors` AND it works on Android. So it’s really hard for me to believe that it’s an Environment problem. What can I clear/reset/remove else?

Comment: You said "I am unable to duplicated your issue". Did you try with a control that inherits from Grid with its own custom event?

Comment: No, as I don't have time to do that. If it doesn't work with your custom grid then the issue may be there.  If worked with Corcav, then just continue to use Corcav.behaviors.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I know that I'm probably a pain in the ass. I will try to build the simplest possible project, maybe I will find this. But I have one more **VERY IMPORTANT** question though... what pcl profile do you use in each project (PCL, iOS and Android)? I mean, what are your targets? thanks for your time! I really appreciate it

Comment: I use the Prism Template Pack to create my projects. So whatever they target :)

Comment: Thanks Brian, btw I solved my problem (xaml compile saved me) :)