# EventToCommandBehavior not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms project. Before Prism 6.3 I used 6.2 with `Corcav.Behaviors` package. I didn't need to pass parameters, so it worked good. But, in iOS project in `AppDelegate` I needed to run this line:

`Corcav.Behaviors.Infrastructure.Init();`

I had a comment: *//Added to prevent iOS linker to strip behaviors assembly out of deployed package.*

Now `EventToCommand` was added to 6.3 version, so I uninstalled `Corcav.Behaviors` package and implemented simple example. In Android everything works great, but the iOS.. I have exception:

[image]

I think this is because now I'm missing this line: `Corcav.Behaviors.Infrastructure.Init();`

**My example:**

**VIEW**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:TestApp.Mobile.Views"
             xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms" 
             x:Class="TestApp.Mobile.Views.StartPage">
  <v:TestGrid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <v:TestGrid.Behaviors>
      <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="OnTestTapped" 
                                        Command="{Binding OnTestTappedCommand}" 
                                        EventArgsParameterPath="Foo"/>
    </v:TestGrid.Behaviors>
  </v:TestGrid>
</ContentPage>
```

my custom gird:

```
public class TestGrid : Grid
{
    public event EventHandler<OnTouchedEventArgs> OnTestTapped;

    public TestGrid()
    {
        var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 };
        tgr.Tapped += Tgr_Tapped;
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
    }

    private void Tgr_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTouchedEventArgs args = new OnTouchedEventArgs(6);
        OnTestTapped?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class StartPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private bool _canExecute;
    private ICommand onTestTappedCommand;

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        _canExecute = true;
    }

    public ICommand OnTestTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return onTestTappedCommand ?? (onTestTappedCommand = 
                    new Command<int>((foo) => HandleEvent(foo), 
                                     (foo) => CanExecute(foo)));
        }
    }

    public async void HandleEvent(int a)
    {
        _canExecute = false;
        Status = $"Working with parameter={a}...";
        Debug.WriteLine("Test with param=" + a);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Status = "Done";
        _canExecute = true;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(int a)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }
}
```

.. and my custom EventArgs:

```
public class OnTouchedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    public OnTouchedEventArgs(int foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}
```

I works 100% on Android, doesn't work on iOS.

**QUESTION:**
**How can I Infrastructure.Init in `Prism.Behaviors`?**

**EDIT:**

I think there might be more errors than I thought... as you can see in my ViewModel, I'm using `ICommand` and `Command` class from `Xamarin.Forms` namespace:

```
    private ICommand onTestTappedCommand;        
    public ICommand OnTestTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return onTestTappedCommand ?? (onTestTappedCommand = 
                    new Command<int>((foo) => HandleEvent(foo), 
                                     (foo) => CanExecute(foo)));
        }
    }
```

It works on Android, BUT.. when I change to `DelegateCommand`:

```
        return onTestTappedCommand ?? (onTestTappedCommand = 
                new DelegateCommand<int>((foo) => HandleEvent(foo), 
                                 (foo) => CanExecute(foo)));
```

Android doesn't work as well. Then I have a runtime exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

and.. the project complies, but in Start.xaml.cs I have an error:

> InitializeComponent() does not exist in the current context

PS. Please help me, and please don't tell me to clear the solution/ remove bin obj folders... it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no init needed. From the exception you are showing my suggestion would be to do a complete clean and rebuild. Make sure that all of the files in your `obj` and `bin` folders are deleted.

#### ViewModel

```
public DelegateCommand<string> PersonSelectedCommand => new DelegateCommand<string>(OnPersonSelectedCommandExecuted);

public ObservableRangeCollection<string> People { get; set; }

void OnPersonSelectedCommandExecuted(string name)
{
    _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Person Selected", name, "Ok" );
}
```

#### View

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding PersonSelectedCommand}" 
                                          EventName="ItemTapped"
                                          EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I removed all bin, obj forlders. Even packages. Restarted Visual Studio. Opened in as admin, restored packages... did not work. Obviously I don't want to add behaviors to existing controls. I have a control that inherit from `Grid`. Is there a working sample somewhere? I think it might be a bug

Comment: Uninstall the apps from your emulators. I have no issues using the EventToCommandBehavior.

Comment: Also, make sure you have upraged all your projects to thw correct NuGet packages.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Is there a difference between using Xamarin.Forms.Command and Prism's DelegateCommand? Which one do you use?

Comment: Yes and no. They behave the exact same, but the Prism version has more features such as ObservesProperty and ObserveCanExecute

Comment: @BrianLagunas here's the simplest possible solution: https://github.com/LouisaBickley/PrismDemo I works great on Android, but on iOS I'm still getting the same weird exception :/ I wonder if this works on your machine

Comment: @LouisaBickley it works fine on mine. I know this is just a simple demo solution, but you might want to try turning on XamlCompilation. It does improve performance, and more importantly (for debugging) it'll alert you if there is a problem in your Xaml before your app starts up and crashes.

Comment: @DanS. Thanks! I will definitely install XamlCompilation. But this is weird. I posted this project on Xamarin Forums - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/262453#Comment_262453 and NMackay fixed it by adding IoC container. Are you sure it works on iOS "as is"? Or did you made some changes?

Comment: @LouisaBickley add `[assembly: XamlCompilation( XamlCompilationOptions.Compile )]` to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` and it works just fine

Comment: Hmm.. I don't have `AssemblyInfo.cs` Am I missing something ?

Comment: https://github.com/LouisaBickley/PrismDemo/blob/master/PrismDemo/PrismDemo/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: Thanks Dan! I was looking for a class... ehh. I added it and it worked. In the view I didn't even use I had `Corcav.Behaviours` namespace left. Thanks again!