# Xamarin EventToCommandBehavior does not wire up the AssociatedObject

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm in Xamarin and I am trying to coax an event into a command [using the EventToCommandBehavior trick](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/). The sample code I am following is [also described here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs). problem I'm having is that the `BehaviorBase`'s `OnAttachedTo` override isn't firing and this means that the event wire-up isn't happening.

**How do I make these commands fire?**

A secondary issue is that the whole view doesn't load while this issue is present. If I comment out the XAML, the view works.  Maybe this is a clue?  Why wouldn't the whole view load because of this?  I would think that only the behavior wouldn't work, not the entire view.

[My question is similar to this one, but the issue is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907333/xamarin-forms-eventtocommandbehavior).

Now for the details:

I've copied over, from the sample the two classes `BehaviorBase` and `EventToCommandBehavior`. [The code comes from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs).

**My View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyPage" xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views;assembly=MyApp" xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyApp.Behaviors;assembly=MyApp" xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters;assembly=MyApp">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Disappearing" Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}" />
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>-->
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In my ViewModel, I have the command `AppearingCommand` and `DisappearingCommand`. The View's code-behind has just the constructor.

When I launch this page, `OnEventNameChange` fires in `EventToCommandBehavior`, but `behavior.AssociatedObject` is null, so it quits.  That variable is null because `OnAttachedTo` never fires.  Why not?  What am I doing wrong?

This Fires:

```
private static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;
    if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
    string newEventName = (string)newValue;

    behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);
    behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);
}
```

But this never does:

```
protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    RegisterEvent(EventName);
}
```

The `base.OnAttachedTo` is what sets `behavior.AssociatedObject` to something.  Here's a copy of it:

```
protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    AssociatedObject = bindable;

    if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
    {
        BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
    }

    bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting an instance of your ViewModel to the page's BindingContext?

Comment: It's elsewhere and it's the usual code `var v = new MyView(); v.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. The solution is to change the base class of the `EventToCommandBehavior` class from `BehaviorBase<View>` to `BehaviorBase<VisualElement>`. So it should be the following:

```cs
public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<VisualElement>
{
    ...
}
```